# How can Iconvert Matlab code into python :- For UT (Universal Time) to LST (Local Sidereal Time) time conversion with incrementing date time

Tags: python, matlab

I have a user defined function UT2LSTmine in matlab. I want to convert the same function into Python working in exact way as it does in matlab. I am new to python programming. I tried alot . I also used online conversion apps for Matlab to Python (OMPC). It is not working as per my requirement.

The function should take start universal time (UT) and convert into Local Sidereal time (LST) , taking incrementing date and time into consideration.

Function to convert the UT hours, min, sec to LST hours, min, sec at GBD
This fuction takes the input from the obsever such as yr,mn,dd,uth,htm,uts. Returns the converted lsth, lstm, lsts. This fuction also checks for 24 hours input and automatically increments the day.

```
function [t] = UT2LSTmine(varargin)

yr = varargin{1};
mn = varargin{2};
dd = varargin{3};
uth = varargin{4};
utm = varargin{5};
uts = varargin{6};

t=[yr,mn,dd,uth,utm,uts];

format long g ;

gbdlong = 5.06138;

%%% Compute Julian Date for the given date

x=[t(1,1), t(1,2), t(1,3), 0,0,0.5];
[~,indx]=ismember(x,t,'rows');%for 24 hours check
if(indx > 0)
t(indx:end,3)=t(indx:end,3)+1;%Incrementing the day manually commented                       for RTLSDR on 30th MA
x=[t(indx,1), t(indx,2), t(indx,3), 23,59,59];
end

%%% Compute Local time & UT for the given IST
utd = t(:,4) + (t(:,5)./60) + (t(:,6)/3600);

for i=1:1:length(t)

julday(i) = juliandate(t(i,1),t(i,2),t(i,3)) + 0.5000000;
jd(i) = julday(i) - 0.5; %%% JD @ 0h UT
T(i) = (jd(i) - 2451545.0)/36525;  %%% Time interval since 2000 jan 1    
12h UT


%%% Compute Gmst @ 0h UT
gmst0(i) = 24110.54841 + (8640184.812866 * T(i)) + (0.093104 * T(i) *  
T(i)) - (0.000006200 * T(i) * T(i) * T(i)); 

%%% Convert Gmst to Hours

gmst0(i) = gmst0(i) / (86400.0); %%% gmst0 in days
gmst0(i) = gmst0(i) - floor(gmst0(i)); %%% Get the fraction of the day
gmst0(i) =  gmst0(i) * 24.0;  %%% Convert into hours
if (gmst0(i) < -0.0000001);
gmst0(i) = gmst0(i) + 24;
end

%%% Compute equivalent of mean sidreal time interval from oh to UT of
%%% intrest


mst(i) = utd(i) * 1.0027379094;
if ( mst(i) - 24.0 > 0.000001);
mst(i) = mst(i) - 24.0;
end

%%% Greenwitch mean sidreal time @ required UT

gmst(i) = gmst0(i) + mst(i);
if ( gmst(i) - 24.0 > 0.000001);
gmst(i) =gmst(i) - 24.0;
end

%%% Local mean sidreal time

lst(i) = gmst(i) + gbdlong;
if ( lst(i) > 24.0);    
lst(i) = lst(i) - 24.0;    
else if ( lst(i) < 0);    
lst(i) = lst(i) + 24.0;
else    
lst(i) = lst(i);
end

lsth(i) = floor(lst(i));
lstm1(i) = (lst(i) - floor(lsth(i))) * 60.0;
lstm(i) = floor(lstm1(i));
lsts(i) = (lstm1(i) - floor(lstm(i))) * 60.0;


% IST corresponding to the given UT

istd(i) = utd(i) + 5.5; 
if ( istd(i) > 24.0);    
ist(i) = istd(i) - 24.0;    
elseif ( istd(i) < 0);    
ist(i) = istd(i) + 24.0;
else    
ist(i) = istd(i);
end
isth(i) = floor(ist(i));
istm(i) = (ist(i) - floor(ist(i))) * 60;
ists(i) = (istm(i) - floor(istm(i))) * 60;
t(i,4)=lsth(i);t(i,5)=lstm(i);t(i,6)=lsts(i);

end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%For checking 24hours condition for LST%%%%%

 [~,index]=ismember(x,t,'rows');%for 24 hours check

 if(indx > 0 & index == 0)

 t(indx:end,3)=t(indx:end,3)-1;%If LST not completed 24 hours then do 1     
 day substraction do to the increment of UT 

 end
```

I have tried this -

```
 import numpy as np
 def UT2LSTmine(*args):
#Function to convert the UT hours, min, sec to LST hours, min, sec at GBD
#  This fuction takes the input from the obsever such as
#  yr,mn,dd,uth,htm,uts. Returs the converted lsth, lstm, lsts
#This fuction also checks for 24 hours input and automatically increments
#the day
 yr = args[:,0]
 mn = args[:,1]
 dd = args[:,2]
 uth = args[:,3]
 utm = args[:,4]
 uts = args[:,5]

 t = [yr, mn, dd, uth, utm, uts]

 format('long', 'g')
 #gbdlong = 5.162351852;%for GBD

 gbdlong = 5.06138#for IIT Indore

 #########Compute Julian Date for the given date

 x = [t(1, 1), t(1, 2), t(1, 3), 0, 0, 0.5]
 ismember(x, t, 'rows')  #for 24 hours check
 for i in x:
    index = np.where(t==i)[0]
    if index.size == 0:
        yield 0
    else:
        yield index

    if (index > 0): 
        t[slice[index:stop], 3]=  t(slice[index:end], 3) + 1           #Incrementing the day manually commented for
    #RTLSDR on 30th MA
     x = [t(index, 1), t(index, 2), t(index, 3), 23, 59, 59]


     ##### Compute Local time & UT for the given IST
     utd = t(slice[:], 4) + (t(slice[:], 5) / 60) + (t(slice[:], 6) / 3600)

     for i in slice[1:1:length(t)]:

        julday[i] = juliandate(t(i, 1), t(i, 2), t(i, 3)) + 0.5000000
        jd[i]= julday(i) - 0.5        #%% JD @ 0h UT
        T[i] = (jd(i) - 2451545.0) / 36525        #%% Time interval      since 2000 jan 1 12h UT

         ########Compute Gmst @ 0h UT
         gmst0[i] = 24110.54841 + (8640184.812866 * T(i)) + (0.093104 *     T(i) * T(i)) - (0.000006200 * T(i) * T(i) * T(i))

          ####Convert Gmst to Hours
         gmst0[i] = gmst0(i) / (86400.0)        #%% gmst0 in days
         gmst0[i]= gmst0(i) - floor(gmst0(i))        #%% Get the  fraction of the day
          gmst0[i]= gmst0(i) * 24.0        #%% Convert into hours
          if (gmst0(i) < -0.0000001):
            gmst0[i]= gmst0(i) + 24 
         ###Compute equivalent of mean sidreal time interval from oh to  UT of intrest
            mst[i] = utd(i) * 1.0027379094
            if (mst(i) - 24.0 > 0.000001):
                mst[i] = mst(i) - 24.0
                end

        ###Greenwitch mean sidreal time @ required UT

                gmst[i] = gmst0(i) + mst(i)
                if (gmst(i) - 24.0 > 0.000001):
                    gmst[i] = gmst(i) - 24.0
           # ####Local mean sidreal time

                    lst[i] = gmst(i) + gbdlong
                    if (lst(i) > 24.0):
                        lst[i]= lst(i) - 24.0
                    elif (lst(i) < 0):
                        lst[i]= lst(i) + 24.0
                    else:
                        lst[i]= lst(i)

                        lsth[i]= floor(lst(i))
                        lstm1[i]= (lst(i) - floor(lsth(i))) * 60.0
                        lstm[i]= floor(lstm1(i))
                        lsts[i]= (lstm1(i) - floor(lstm(i))) * 60.0


                        # IST corresponding to the given UT

                        istd[i]= utd(i) + 5.5
                        if (istd(i) > 24.0):
                            ist[i]= istd(i) - 24.0
                        elif (istd(i) < 0):
                            ist[i] = istd(i) + 24.0
                        else:
                            ist[i]= istd(i)

                            isth[i] = floor(ist(i))
                            istm[i]= (ist(i) - floor(ist(i))) * 60
                            ists[i]= (istm(i) - floor(istm(i))) * 60
                            t[i, 4]= lsth(i)
                            t[i, 5] = lstm(i)
                            t[i, 6] = lsts(i)


          ############For checking 24hours condition for LST ###################

                            ismember(x, t,'rows')                                         #for 24 hours check

                            if (logical_and(indx > 0, index == 0)):

                                t[slice[indx:end], 3]=                                               t(slice[indx:end], 3) - 1                                #If LST not completed     24 hours then do 1 day substraction do to the increment of UT
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt in python yet? Could you include it as a code example in your question?

Comment: This code is too long, I suggest you ask a question about the specific part that you are stuck with. You’re not likely to find someone here willing to write so much code for you for free.

Answer (score 1):

Without thorough inspection I spot already multiple issues.
Looking at the programming style the Matlab-code is quite outdated; semi-columns after if-statements; and a function-statement without end-statement.

Furthermore, the function implements a `juliandate()` with doubles which is not supported (anymore?). Therefore, my matlab-version (R2018b) throws an error.
I see that the `juliandate()`-function is literally copied in to the python script, which is, as far as I know, not a function in python.

I do not have a lot of Python knowledge. But i know that the indenting is quite important. The following python code is:

```
if (true):
  doSomething()

  if (true):
    doSomethingElse()
```

equivalent to this matlab code:

```
if true
  doSomething()
    if true
      doSomethingElse()
    end
end
```

Which is clearly not the desired behavior.

It sounds like you found a matlab-function, that you needed in python.
But converting scripts with a online-tool sounds, for me, is a really big red flag.

So, I did some googling and found this:
[Github: Sidereal-Time-Calculator](https://github.com/jhaupt/Sidereal-Time-Calculator).
Which sounds like what you need. It is not a function, but that is possible with not to much work.

Comment: Actually I have recently started programming , so can you help me to implement this function using what you have suggested ( Github: Sidereal-Time-Calculator).